# Stacking Highcharts data in an xrange data series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am creating a gantt chart showing my advertising buys for the year. Everything is working well except when I have data on the same y axis. The data ends up displayed one on top of the other. How can you stack the data show both can be displayed. Here is a JSFIDDlE showing my dilemma. http://jsfiddle.net/tagriffith/a16mgm04/1/

When I want to show the radio spots in the same y (4) series and they have the same run dates the data gets stacked on top of each other. Below is the partial code from the jsfiddle.

```
[{
    name: 'Radio',
    groupPadding: 0,
    borderRadius: 0,
    pointWidth: 20,
    data: [{
        name: 'WLW',
        x: Date.UTC(2015, 12, 4),
        x2: Date.UTC(2015, 12, 20),
        y: 4
      }, {
        name: 'WNKU',
        x: Date.UTC(2015, 12, 4),
        x2: Date.UTC(2015, 12, 20),
        y: 4
      },

      {
        name: 'WGUC',
        x: Date.UTC(2015, 12, 4),
        x2: Date.UTC(2015, 12, 20),
        y: 4
      },]]
```

Comment: "except when I have data on the same y axis" - do you mean same y value in same series? Do you want to group data points from the same series? This is not possible. Series can be grouped - as they are by default. If you want your data points to be displayed with different y values, then you would have to set those values - e.g. process your data before using it in Highcharts.

Comment: I want the same y value, but when I enter the same y value as in my code above it ends up placing the data one on top of each other. I have tried grouping: true; and grouping false. It still doesn't separate the data so that you can visually see them.

Comment: Points in a single series with same y values will overlap each other and there is no grouping of data points in the same series. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

**New answer:**

Grouping data points with same `y` values, from the same series is not possible. Series can be grouped - as they are by default. If you want your data points to be displayed with different y values, then you would have to set those values - e.g. process your data before using it in Highcharts. Series can be linked to each other, so they will appear and behave as one - performance might slight drop and custom code might need a little adjustments.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/m7av02t7/

**Previous answer:**

To get all series in a single group and allow overlapping of points with same values you could set [`grouping`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.grouping) to `false` in `plotOptions.series`.

```
...
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    grouping: false,
    ...
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8zy6mh0m/

Comment: I tried that, but it still doesn't work. Even if you look at your jsfiddle, all of the radio stations that have ads running the same days are overlapping on top of each other. You should be able to see two more radio stations, but you only see the one.